# Use of swift actor in delegate facade

Tags: ios, swift, async-await, concurrency, actor

I was reading through this blog, as I have a similar use-case: https://kelvas09.github.io/blog/posts/closure-delegate-to-async/

I noticed the following snippet:

```
actor BluetoothLEScanWrapper {

enum BluetoothLEScanError: Error {
    case bluetoothNotAvailable
}

private let bluetoothLEDelegate: BluetoothLEDelegate = BluetoothLEDelegate()
private var activeTask: Task<[BluetoothLEDevice], Error>?

func scan(for seconds: Double = 3.0) async throws -> [BluetoothLEDevice] {

    if let existingTask = activeTask {
        return try await existingTask.value
    }

    let task = Task<[BluetoothLEDevice], Error> {
        guard bluetoothLEDelegate.bluetoothIsOn else {
            activeTask = nil
            throw BluetoothLEScanError.bluetoothNotAvailable
        }

        self.bluetoothLEDelegate.central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil)

        try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: (UInt64(seconds) * 1_000_000_000))

        let devices = bluetoothLEDelegate.foundPeripheral.compactMap { BluetoothLEDevice(peripheral: $0) }

        bluetoothLEDelegate.central.stopScan()
        bluetoothLEDelegate.foundPeripheral = []

        activeTask = nil

        return devices
    }

    activeTask = task

    return try await task.value

}
...
```

The author specifically calls attention to the use of actor. As I understand it, this is to avoid data races with `activeTask` in case `scan()` is called repeatedly. Is my understanding correct? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Unrelated, but I’d advise against `UInt64(seconds) * 1_000_000_000`, because you will lose the fractional seconds. It’s misleading to accept a `Double` only to round it. I’d suggest `Task.sleep(nanoseconds: UInt64(seconds * 1_000_000_000))` (or `Task.sleep(for: .seconds(seconds))`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. Actors are used to prevent data races. See WWDC videos [Protect mutable state with Swift actors](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10133) and [Eliminate data races using Swift Concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110351/). Or see [The Swift Programming Language: Concurrency: Actors](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/concurrency#Actors).

The `scan` method will be isolated to the actor, as will the `Task` it creates.